# Var/Array Random Selection

Tags: javascript

I'm a hobbyist coder and I'm working on a side project. I want the "Random" coding at the bottom of this list of variables (which functions as an ...Array right?) to randomly select specifically from each set of variables. How do I make this work?

```
    var flanks = [
    "Androxus-Flank",
    "Zhin-Flank",
    "Buck-Flank",
    "Evie-Flank",
    "Lex-Flank",
    "Maeve-Flank",
    "Skye-Flank",
    "Talus-Flank"

];

var frontline = [
    "Ash-Frontline",
    "Barik-Frontline",
    "Fernando-Frontline",
    "Inara-Frontline",
    "Makoa-Frontline",
    "Torvald-Frontline",
    "Ruckus-Frontline"

];

var damage = [
    "Bomb King-Damage",
    "Tyra-Damage",
    "Viktor-Damage",
    "Willo-Damage",
    "Kinessa-Damage",
    "Lian-Damage",
    "Sha Lin-Damage",
    "Strix-Damage",
    "Cassie-Damage",
    "Drogoz-Damage"

];

var support = [
    "Grohk-Support",
    "Grover-Support",
    "Mal'Damba-Support",
    "Pip-Support",
    "Jenos-Support",
    "Seris-Support",
    "Ying-Support"

];

$("#button").click(function() { 
    $("#flanks").text(flanks[Math.floor(Math.random() * flanks.8)]);
    $("#frontline").text(frontline[Math.floor(Math.random() * frontline.7)]);
    $("#damage").text(damage[Math.floor(Math.random() * damage.10)]);
    $("#support").text(support[Math.floor(Math.random() * support.7)]);
});
```

and this is the html I'm building alongside it; if anyone wouldn't mind proofreading.

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">Basic Functioning Demo for 'The Unofficial Hi-Rez Paladins' Champion Roulette'
   </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <ul>
      <li><strong>Flank</strong>--<span id="flanks"></span></li>
      <li><strong>Frontline</strong>--<span id="frontline"></span></li>
      <li><strong>Damage</strong>--<span id=damage></span></li>
      <li><strong>Support</strong>--<span id="support"></span></li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="panel-footer">
      <a href="#" id="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block text-center">R o l l</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/u9nFQuH.png" class="center"/>
```

Comment: `flank`, `frontline`, `damage` and `support` all seem like playstyles... What _are_ those arrays, in relation to what you're trying to set, below?

Comment: I forgot to update those before pasting the code I'm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You can still update tehm, Ben. Please do.

Comment: did just that; any tips?

Comment: Ben, `flanks.8` and similar isn't valid JavaScript... What were you trying to do there?

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you just refer to the correct arrays

For example:

```
$("#race").text(races[Math.round((Math.random() * 32))]);
```

There is no races array

try changing races to flank

```
$("#race").text(flank[Math.round((Math.random() * 32))]);
```

An easy way to see if this is working is to use console logs

```
console.log(flank[Math.round((Math.random() * 32))]);
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I make this work?

Change the ***multiplier*** to array's (`race` in this case) length and `Math.round` with `Math.floor` so that you don't get `undefined`

```
$( "#race" ).text( races[ Math.floor( Math.random() * races.length ) ] );
```

Comment: by the "array length value" you mean the length of the variable list; correct?

Comment: @BenJohnsick Yes, I have clarified in my answer itself just now.

Comment: I still think I have an obvious flaw somewhere because the function isn't working.